# Preventing ASIHTTPRequest from following HTTP 303 See Other

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, asihttprequest

I'm writing an iPhone Application using the ASIHTTPRequest (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library for REST interactions to a Web App's RESTful services.

I am currently facing a bug where I am receiving a 200 OK from one of these pages and there is no body. Additionally, I noticed that the headers are blank after the request has been completed, but the headers were not blank beforehand (they were filled with an OAuth Authentication).

Through an over-complicated network / proxy setup, I was able to verify that I am receiving a 303 (as expected) and that ASIHTTPRequest is following that request (as semi-expected). However, since I need to recreate my OAuth authentication headers so that the RESTful services will give me the information I want, I need to **prevent** ASIHTTPRequest from following 303s, and instead to just return the 303 so I can read the Location header myself and create a new request with the appropriate OAuth Headers.

If anybody has had to do this, please let me know how you did it!

Thanks,
Tyler

*Dives off the diving board into the NSAutoreleasePool*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your HTTP status in `request:didReceiveResponseHeaders:` delegate method. Here's the code:

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveResponseHeaders:(NSDictionary *)responseHeaders {
    if(request.responseStatusCode == 303) {
        [request cancel];
    }
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    if(request.responseStatusCode == 303) {
            // here you can call your custom methods
        }
}
```

It will cancel your connection as soon as it receives HTTP headers, so it **will not** load the full page.

Comment: I just found the "setShouldRedirect" method/property of ASIHTTPRequest.